# IOS mutipletouch sequence with touchesBegan and touchesEnded

Tags: ios, touchesbegan

This is for a music ap

User task is to touch and hold the screen with fingers 1, 2 and 3, with a brief time between touches.

If the user then lifts the fingers in the order placed down (1,2,3) then everything works as expected.  So it seems like the mulitpletouchenable, userinteractionenable, etc flags must be correct.

Here is a report
(n is the number of touches return, x and y the location)
(i edited the output file to identify fingers 1, 2, 3

```
    2012-06-27 07:22:36.589 Bowing[757:907]  finger 1 Began n=0,x=190, y=860
    2012-06-27 07:22:37.207 Bowing[757:907]  finger 2 Began n=0,x=346, y=704
    2012-06-27 07:22:37.875 Bowing[757:907]  finger 3 Began n=0,x=580, y=708

    2012-06-27 07:22:38.587 Bowing[757:907]  finger 1 Ended n=0,x=191, y=854
    2012-06-27 07:22:39.252 Bowing[757:907]  finger 2 Ended n=0,x=346, y=722
    2012-06-27 07:22:40.019 Bowing[757:907]  finder 3 Ended n=0,x=585, y=712
```

Life is good

If the user lifts the fingers in reverse order (3,2,1) then no message is sent until finger 1 is lifted; then messages for all three fingers are sent

```
    2012-06-27 07:22:36.589 Bowing[757:907] finger 1 Began n=0,x=190, y=860
    2012-06-27 07:22:37.207 Bowing[757:907] finger 2 Began n=0,x=346, y=704
    2012-06-27 07:22:37.875 Bowing[757:907] finger 3 Began n=0,x=580, y=708

    2012-06-27 07:22:38.587 Bowing[757:907] finger 1 Ended n=0,x=191, y=854
    2012-06-27 07:22:39.252 Bowing[757:907] finger 2 Ended n=0,x=346, y=722
    2012-06-27 07:22:40.019 Bowing[757:907] finger 3 Ended n=0,x=585, y=712
```

Life is not so good.  To reflect what happened on the screen the messages should have arrived in the order finger 3, finger 2, and then finger 1

Here are the responders; works the same regardless if the message to super is there or not

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
//    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [touches objectEnumerator];
    UITouch  *aTouch;
    int counter=0;
    while ((aTouch = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        /* code that acts on the set’s values */
        CGPoint  where=[aTouch locationInView:nil];
        NSLog(@"Began n=%i,x=%3.0f, y=%3.0f",counter,where.x,where.y);
        counter++;
    }

}
// Sent to the receiver when a system event (such as a low-memory warning) cancels a touch   event.
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

//    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [touches objectEnumerator];
    UITouch  *aTouch;
    int counter=0;
    while ((aTouch = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        /* code that acts on the set’s values */
        CGPoint  where=[aTouch locationInView:nil];
        NSLog(@"Cancelled n=%i,x=%3.0f, y=%3.0f",counter,where.x,where.y);
        counter++;
    }

}
```

// Tells the receiver when one or more fingers are raised from a view or window.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
//    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [touches objectEnumerator];
    UITouch  *aTouch;
    int counter=0;
    while ((aTouch = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        /* code that acts on the set’s values */
        CGPoint  where=[aTouch locationInView:nil];
        NSLog(@"Ended n=%i,x=%3.0f, y=%3.0f",counter,where.x,where.y);
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is associated with a uitableview; if the responders are on a view then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:
Touches ended is waiting for all the touches to be finished, which is why when it ended all three touches were sent.
A solution for this could be a nstimer which detects `[touch count];` at 1/32 time intervals, and detects if it increases or decreases.